# Conditionally format if date is same/greater or smaller than current date

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to get my Google sheet to automatically colour a cell **red if the current date is the same or greater than the date in the cell**.

Example: today is **`21/02/2020`**.

The date in the cell is `25/02/2020`. The cell is **green**.

The date in the cell is `21/02/2020`. The cell is **red**.

The date in the cell is `15/02/2020`. The cell is **red**.

How can I achieve this?

The date in the cell will be changing pretty often. It's to indicate when an update is due. When the update has been completed, the date in that cell will change. This will of course be done manually. I'm just looking to find the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Color everything in red then go to `Format` > `Conditionnal Formatting`

Choose Format cell if

<kbd>Date is after</kbd> >

<kbd>Exact date</kbd>  >

<kbd>Cell reference</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under **`Custom formula is`** and for the same range *(in our example `S1:S`)*, you should use the following 2 formulas.
*(For reference only the current date `2/22/2020` is shown in cell `R1`)*,

**For dates greater than the current date**. *(green)*

```
=IF(LEN(S1)>0,IF(S1>DATEVALUE(TODAY()),TRUE,FALSE),"")
```

**For dates that are the same or smaller than the current date**. *(red)*

```
=IF(LEN(S1)>0,IF(S1<=DATEVALUE(TODAY()),TRUE,FALSE),"")
```

> *Pro Tip: **In Conditional formatting the order of the rules is very important**, because if they happen to overlap the top ones cancel the lower ones. **But not in this case.** The way the formulas are structured they never overlap.*

[image: Conditional formatting if date is same/greater or smaller than the date in the cell]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.